# ПРАВКА index.html в корне wordpress сайта вместо index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Я фронтэндщик, делаю одностраничник, бюджет ограничен...

Вордпресс знаю но не настолько, чтоб так сделать. Знаю что index.php нужен - через него все запросы идут.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при обращении юзера к корню сайта, выдавать ему только index.html, а если внутренние страницы, то уже как положено, с темой и всем остальным. Что лучше для этого - .htaccess???

**UPD 0.0.1**

Или убрать вордпресс в подпапку, а в корень сайта положить index.html

**UPD 0.0.2**

Или просто сделать шаблон для конкретно первой страницы со своим пустым хедером и футером и в php прописать, чтоб он грабил index.html в корне сайта?

Comment: отредактировали конечно классно. ссори фор май русиш, только когда я писал "к сайту/" я имел ввиду именно "к сайту/" , тоесть к его корню, может ответите какая лучше практика по теме вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно трогать index.php ни в теме ни тем более в корне сайта.
Нужно создать [шаблон главной страницы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.93.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B) и скопировать (в нужное место! Не поломав подключение ВП) в него содержимое index.html.

Или создать [шаблон страницы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.88.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86) и назначить его для главной в админке.
index.html удалить.

Comment: ну первый абзац это мой UPD 0.0.2

Comment: просто это не лучшая практика на мой взгляд, мне нужен именно html документ, т.к. он создается динамически, не в wordpress`е, и нет возможности его привязывать к шаблону, и дизайн меняется и структура документа часто тоже, вот такая вот загвоздка, да и вообще это не проблема, просто хочу узнать лучшую практику в этом...

Comment: по ходу я слишком поскромничал со знанием вордпресса))) что меня на эти страницы послали

Comment: Это 2 варианта ПРАВИЛЬНОЙ практики. Как частный случай обоих можно в указанные шаблоны инклудить содержимое html, но только содержимое body. Те либо выкладывать неполный html, либо через скрипт парсить и удалять до body (включительно) и после (также включительно)

Comment: значит грабить index.html из корня сайта? щас чет подумал - опять же php в этом задействовать, лучше я все-таки в подпапку уберу wordpress, пусть себе лежит никого не трогает, а когда тыкнут на ссылку внутренней она и подгрузится в нужный блок на страничке index.html или если javascript не включен то юзер перейдет на страницу, а чтоб так произошло просто в javascripte пропишу чтоб при клике брал href ссылки, дописывал в него "?minpage" а в header.php и footer.php пропишу чтоб если isset "minpage" то содержимое  heder adn footer не выдавать

Comment: в связи с этим щас еще один вопрос попрет

Comment: А кому-то потом это исправлять..

Comment: вот он https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656885/wordpress-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-htaccess

Comment: да не исправлять - это уже кто-то сделал, а теперь надо к этому вордпресс, чтоб новости там блоги всю мелочь на страничке этой же выводить