# wordpress в подпапке корня сайта как удалить из адресной строки на htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

wordpress лежит в подпапке в корне сайта ну типа http://site.name/wordpress

как из строки браузера удалить(да и не только из строки а вообще чтоб обращения к папке шли минуя "wordpress" в запросе)

надо как-то на htaccess

Answer (score 2):

> как из строки браузера удалить(да и не только из строки а вообще чтоб
>   обращения к папке шли минуя "wordpress" в запросе)

Изучаем ман: [Размещаем WordPress в отдельном каталоге](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC_WordPress_%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5) и готовимся к разного рода гемороями с темами/плагинами.

Comment: ман хороший плюс+, но не то, я уже опредилился со стрктурой, мне от пресса нужен только контент, все, а что-то делать на чем-то другом нет  времени желания да и платят не так много чтоб собирать что-то на том же yii, яб ваще html файликов накидал в папку, но вот стили при переходе без javascript`а лучше уж пускай этим вордпресс занимается